# how to make trigger execute only when user directly affect table through SSMS. Not when stored procedures executes

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to make trigger execute only when user directly make change in table from SQL Server management studio. But not When table affected by the application flow of execution.

My purpose is To keep track of changes which made by the developers on the table manually.

Comment: Are the developers "casual" or "malicious"? I.e. you can do some things if everything accessing the database is good natured, but it's significantly more complicated if you're trying to do something that the developers mustn't be able to circumvent with additional knowledge of how the differences are detected.

Comment: what prevents developers from doing DISABLE TRIGGER?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever :- they are casual developer, sometimes developers ought to make change in table, flexible to the customer, some times change bring value mismatch in the report at the end of year or month, this occurs when developer missed to make the change in all relational tables. I just want to keep the record before update and after update in an additional table or archive table.

Comment: @TapakahUa Nothing prevent developers from doing Disable Trigger. All i want is Let the developer make change in table, but i need previous and after change value in another table.. But i don't want trigger execute when Stored Procedures are executed by front-end application

Answer (score 0):

You may check [APP_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql) in the trigger

Upd. Example

```
CREATE TABLE mytab (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name nvarchar(50)
)
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER mytab_on_insert ON mytab INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF APP_NAME() = 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query'
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytab (id, name) SELECT id, name FROM inserted
  END
END
GO
```

Now run these statements from SSMS:

```
INSERT INTO mytab (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Value 1')
SELECT * FROM mytab
```

SQL Server returns inserted row as expected

```
id          name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Value 1

(1 row affected)
```

Now run from sqlcmd

```
INSERT INTO mytab (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Value 2')
SELECT * FROM mytab
```

The trigger doesn't insert the row and SELECT returns the same result.

Comment: Note that any arbitrary application name can be specified from SSMS using Additional Connection Parameters.

Comment: @serge I tried like this ` ALTER TRigger Trigger_Test
ON tbl_dep_itran_header
AFTER Insert
AS
BEGiN
 IF( APP_NAME() = 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query')
  Insert Into Test_Table VALUES(1)
 Else 
  Insert Into Test_Table VALUES(2)
END
` . When i make transaction through my application. If case becomes true.  . Note i use stored procedure for insert record through application.

Comment: I just added the example

Comment: did you try with stored procedure ?. Because i am using stored procedure for all transaction from front-end.

Comment: The initial question is about trigger. It works within stored procedure too.